# css :not selector to target everything but a condition

Tags: html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/m7qLdstp/1/

```
<style>
:not(div p), p{
  color: red
}
</style>

<p>This is a paragraph that should be red.</p>
<div><p>This is a paragraph that should not be red.</p></div>
```

Is it possible to use the css [:not](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_not.asp) selector to (in this case) turn all `<p>` color red, except for any `<p>` instead a `<div>`?

I ran a few different variations on jsfiddle but cannot get it to work?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following will change the color of all `<p>` elements that are not direct descendants of a `<div>`:

```
:not(div) > p{
    color: red;
}
```

**[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/koala_dev/m7qLdstp/2/)**

Answer (score 1):

You could just target them separately

```
p{
  color: red
}

div p{color:black}
```

**[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0p5crumv/)**

it works because `div p` is more specific than `p`

Answer (score 0):

According to [CSS-Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/n/not/), :not() selector can take only a "simple selector", defined as:

> a Type Selector, Universal Selector, Attribute Selector, Class Selector, ID Selector, or Pseudo Class Selector

but:

> may not contain additonal selectors or any pseudo-element selectors.

However, as other answers suggest, there are ways you could work around this issue and accomplish the behavior at least in this example case and other simple cases.